# How to run an app on a device using visual studio (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

Yesterday i installed visual studio, and i've never work with xamarin before, my question is how can i run an app on my android device?

I didnt install any SDK because i was using Android studio before and i was able to run an app on my device, somehow i cannot do this on visual.

I attach a picture of the screen. [image: picture]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Once you connect your device to the system it will automatically appear.

Comment: I connect it but it doesn't show up, when i run it it open the emulator @Jaymin

Comment: Have you checked for USB drivers?

Comment: I know whats happening, i have forgotten that i reset my cellphone last week, feel so dumb.

Comment: Check developer options on your device to enable debugging